# Problems extending a ListSet with a concrete type

Tags: scala

Trying to extend a ListSet with a concrete type in the Pile class, and then every time an ListSet[ConcreteType] instance is needed, I would pass an Pile instance

```
class Pile extends ListSet[Card]{
  def this(cards: ListSet[Card]){
    this()
    this ++ cards
  }
  def draw(amount: Int = 1): (Pile, Pile) = this.splitAt(amount)
}
```

In the 'draw' method, the compiler accuses 'Expression of type (ListSet[Card], ListSet[Card]) doesnt conform to the expected type(Pile, Pile)', but a simple:

```
type Pile = ListSet[Card]
```

inside the Pile body solves the problem ..
I am really supposed to use the type alias AND the extend keyword? (id really like to create a new class instead of just giving an alias to it)

ps: Is my constructor looking like madness? It is the only way I can figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that `splitAt` returns `ListSet[Card]`, which is not a Pile, although your `Pile` extends `ListSet[Card]`.

A way to avoid this problem is the convert the result from `splitAt` to `Pile`s.

```
def draw(amount: Int = 1): (Pile, Pile) = {
  val (a,b) = this.splitAt(amount)
  (new Pile(a), new Pile(b))
}
```

**Another Idea.**

You only want to return `Pile`s in order to have the `draw` method available for the result. You could work with an implicit class here. Now all instances of `ListSet[Card]` have the draw method.

```
implicit class Pile(cards: ListSet[Card]) {
  def draw(amount: Int = 1) = cards.splitAt(amount)
}
```

Small example.

```
type Card = Int

val pile = ListSet(1,2,3,4,5)

val (drawn, remaining) = pile.draw()

val (nextDrawn, nextRemaining) = remaining.draw(2)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same "Another Idea" but was lazy. I will just add that I recommend reading this debate amongst scala library developers before attempting to subtype something from the collections library. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/R4fTU_5XVZs/W47WsAE70LsJ